# Is it possible to move an edge along the z-axes with the same amount of degrees from another object?

Tags: edit-mode

Is it possible to move an edge along the z-axes with the same amount of degrees from another object?

I want to move the selected edge, as you can see in the picture below, upwards along the z-axes. I want to get the exact same result as the object next to it. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the  **Snap** drop-down menu choose the *Snap To* **Vertex** and  *Snap With* **Active** options.

Make a duplicate of the vertex <kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the lower end of the slope. This will be used as the active vertex when snapping.

<kbd>Shft</kbd> select the two vertices of the edge to be moved and then add the duplicated vertex to the selection. (The last vertex will become the active vertex).

<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> (to confine movement to along the Z axis) and while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, (this is the shortcut key that temporarily enables snapping) move the mouse cursor towards the vertex at the upper end of the slope until a little orange circle surrounds this vertex indicating that the active vertex is snapped to its Z hight. Validate with <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Select the the duplicated vertex and delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there are other ways but some fiddlings, for example you could duplicate the top face (or just one edge) of your reference object, separate, join it to your new object and stick it to its vertices (here with *Snap to Vertex* and *Auto Merge* options enabled):

[image]

Or you could use the *MeasureIt* addon to get the angle (once activated, select the vertices from top to bottom, open the *N panel > View > MeasureIt Tools*, click on the *Show* button then *Angle*):

[image]

Remember the angle and move up the edge of your new object until you have the same:

[image]

Comment: When I try your first method, my vertices are not snapping together. Do you have Snap With Closest or something else enabled?
When I try your second method, my measurelt says I need to select three vertices, but I have the exact same vertices selected as you.

Comment: For the snap, choose the Snap With > Active option and make the vertex you want to snap active. For the measureit tool, make sure that you've selected 3 vertices, not 2 or 4, and that you select from top to bottom or from bottom to top, if it doesn't work I don't understand why...

Comment: How do I make a vertex active?
I am exactly doing that. Selecting 3 vertices and going from top to bottom..

Comment: The active vertex is that last selected, it will be white and the other ones orange

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought. I know it now. For some reason I have to use Ctrl to snap

Comment: Oh yes if you don't enable the Snap option (magnet icon) you need to press Crrl

Comment: Aaaah! Of course! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way, with Snap set to 'With': 'Active' ...

- Create a Custom Orientation from the slope you want to match
- Set Snap 'To': 'Edge'
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> duplicate a vertex from the low side of the flat top face, and snap to a rear vertical edge
- Set Snap 'To': 'Vertex'
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> snap  the rear horizontal edge to the 'marker' vertex, back in Global transform orientation.

[image]

Or, more simply, if you know the depths match,

- With snap set to 'To': 'Vertex'
- Copy the entire slope, snap to corresponding location
- Use the rear end of the offset duplicate edge as a snap target:

[image]

.. and, in both cases,  <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > By Distance, to clean up.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another one... and to show that we can paste a value while transforming the mesh.

With snap to vertex activated, mesure the height difference of the first figure.

Copy the value <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>,

then undo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

Select the edge of the other shape,

then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>minus</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (grab along Z minus the pasted value).

[image]